# How to get certain image attributes for all images in a given folder, and build objects with the data?

Tags: php, reactjs

So I have a folder, I'm doing something like this to get the image names:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $customDir = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    if (empty($customDir)) {
        $customDir = 'gallery';
    }
    chdir($customDir);
    $dir = scandir('.');
    krsort($dir);
    echo json_encode(array_values($dir));
?>
```

I'm passing the folder name outside, if I don't pass it then it changes to `gallery` as default. The response is an array of strings, each string is the filename + extension.

What I would like to do instead, is also get image's `Description`, which has `Title`, `Tags`, `Comments`, `Rating`, `Subject` (Right click, Details, on Windows). I don't care about all of those, but I'd like to add a `Title` which to then use for `caption` when I generate the gallery. :) And the response would be something like:

```
[
  {
    file: 'image1.jpg',
    title: 'caption here',
  },
  {
    file: 'image1.jpg',
    title: 'caption here',
  },
]
```

The front-end is React, not CMS, I'm just using PHP as an API for this. The alternative is to put this data in a DB table (so reference each image), but I already set it up and adding captions to the response would simplify the effort a lot.

What's a good way to go about it?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to retrieve header values from your image files. If so take a look at [exif-read-data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).

Comment: It's there, in `IFD0` and the `Title` that I see on windows is actually called `ImageDescription`. I looped through the file names, created objects, put in an array and just `json_encode()`'ed the whole thing, seems good. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You should probably post this as an answer so your question is shown as resolved. (I can post that PHP function too as an answer that you'd mark as accepted, if you prefer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I understood correctly, you want to retrieve header values from
>   your image files. If so take a look at exif-read-data. – Jeto

This had the data I needed.

Code looks like this now:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $customDir = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    if (empty($customDir)) {
        $customDir = 'gallery';
    }
    chdir($customDir);
    $dir = scandir('.');
    $files = array();
    // krsort($dir);
    foreach($dir as $file) {
        $exif = exif_read_data($file, 0, true);
        array_push($files, [
              'src'   => $file,
              'caption' => trim($exif['IFD0']['ImageDescription'])
            ]);
    }
    echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Mind the headers if re-using, I'm also passing the folder from outside.